# How to fix metal bulkhead holes caused by rust

Tags: metal, rust-removal, rust-proofing

At the top of my bulkhead in the center of the seam where the water drains, there are some holes caused by rust.  Each about 1/2 inch in length, 1/4 in height.  Since the rest of the structure is ok, I would like to identify a way to remove the rust, and patch the holes.

What sort of products are there that I can apply to fill the holes? 
I plan to just sand off the rust.  Then apply some rustoleum primer/paint.

Maybe I am over thinking this and I just need to buy some bondo and get to work?
but wondering if there are some better products for small areas that need to be "shaped" or "molded".  The radius of the metal bend is a bit wider then a pencil.

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Bondo is good for filling dents or depressions, and will probably do fine for completely filling small holes of this size.

Epoxy putty is also a choice, often found in the US with either plumbing or car repair supplies.  JB Weld is one common brand name; it has metal powder mixed in it so it dries very hard and durable.